# Optimal size of the Impala Scratch directory

Tags: impala

Scratch directory size too small (there were originally four directories set up - one per node).  Cloudera support got rid of one of them, but unclear if this is the right configuration.

How do you decide optimal size of the Impala Scratch directory?

Cheers
mkb

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at (http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/impala_disk_space.html)

Honestly, as long as you have 1 GB of space free in the file system where your /tmp/impala-scratch directory is, you'll be fine. Maybe the other directories were taking up too much space?

So run `df -h` to figure out how much available space you have, and make sure your impala-scratch directory isn't larger than that.